# JSON file formatting using Python

Tags: python, json

I'm really new to Python and programming in general so I have no idea how to do this.
I have a JSON file that looks like this

```
{
    "data_0_key_0": "GDPQ",
    "data_0_key_1": "1860",
    "data_0_values_0": "20.89",
    "data_1_key_0": "GDPQ",
    "data_1_key_1": "1861",
    "data_1_values_0": "21.02",
    "data_2_key_0": "GDPQ",
    "data_2_key_1": "1862",
    "data_2_values_0": "19.93",
    "data_3_key_0": "GDPQ",
    "data_3_key_1": "1863",
    "data_3_values_0": "21.48"
}
```

And I would like the end result to look like this

```
{
"1860":"20.89",
"1861":"21.02",
"1862":"19,93",
"1863","21.48"
}
```

So basically

```
{
"data_x_key_1":"data_x_values_0"
}
```

Comment: collect the values while iterating over them and make your dictionary

Comment: I can elaborate on this further, but ask for a different JSON format if possible. This will give you headaches.

Comment: That seems like a pretty bad dupe target for this question.

Comment: let result = {} and number of loop is length of data divide by 3, set result["data_{}_key_1".format(i)] = data["data_{}_values_0".format(i)] for each loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this with a <s>list</s> dict of comprehension:

```
data = {
    "data_0_key_0": "GDPQ",
    "data_0_key_1": "1860",
    "data_0_values_0": "20.89",
    "data_1_key_0": "GDPQ",
    "data_1_key_1": "1861",
    "data_1_values_0": "21.02",
    "data_2_key_0": "GDPQ",
    "data_2_key_1": "1862",
    "data_2_values_0": "19.93",
    "data_3_key_0": "GDPQ",
    "data_3_key_1": "1863",
    "data_3_values_0": "21.48"
}

output = {data[v]:data[v.replace('key_1', 'values_0')] for (k,v) in enumerate(data) if 'key_1' in v }

print(output)
```

**Output**

> {'1860': '20.89', '1861': '21.02', '1862': '19.93', '1863': '21.48'}

Comment: Seems like they are looking for one dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to change you json in à python dictionary for this your could use the json library like that

```
import json

json_values = """ {
    "data_0_key_0": "GDPQ",
    "data_0_key_1": "1860",
    "data_0_values_0": "20.89",
    "data_1_key_0": "GDPQ",
    "data_1_key_1": "1861",
    "data_1_values_0": "21.02",
    "data_2_key_0": "GDPQ",
    "data_2_key_1": "1862",
    "data_2_values_0": "19.93",
    "data_3_key_0": "GDPQ",
    "data_3_key_1": "1863",
    "data_3_values_0": "21.48"
} """

json_dictionary = json.loads(json_values)
```

After that you can just loop over the dictionary indexes like that :

```py
result = {}
for key in json_dictionary:
    if "key_1" in key:
        num = key.split("_")[1]
        value = json_dictionary["data_" + num + "_values_0"]
        result[key] = value
```

If you have any doubt on how does work one of this line, please ask me for an explanation !

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, If you have idea about the count of keys use that value to range :

```
d = {
"data_0_key_0": "GDPQ",
"data_0_key_1": "1860",
"data_0_values_0": "20.89",
"data_1_key_0": "GDPQ",
"data_1_key_1": "1861",
"data_1_values_0": "21.02",
"data_2_key_0": "GDPQ",
"data_2_key_1": "1862",
"data_2_values_0": "19.93",
"data_3_key_0": "GDPQ",
"data_3_key_1": "1863",
"data_3_values_0": "21.48"
}
d_new = dict()
for i in range(10):
    try:
       d_new.update({d["data_"+str(i)+"_key_1"]:d["data_"+str(i)+"_values_0"]})
    except KeyError:
      pass
print(d_new)
```

O/P :

```
{'1860': '20.89', '1861': '21.02', '1862': '19.93', '1863': '21.48'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data = {
    "data_0_key_0": "GDPQ",
    "data_0_key_1": "1860",
    "data_0_values_0": "20.89",
    "data_1_key_0": "GDPQ",
    "data_1_key_1": "1861",
    "data_1_values_0": "21.02",
    "data_2_key_0": "GDPQ",
    "data_2_key_1": "1862",
    "data_2_values_0": "19.93",
    "data_3_key_0": "GDPQ",
    "data_3_key_1": "1863",
    "data_3_values_0": "21.48"
}

new_dict = {}
count=0
for i in data:
    #create dictionary key
    key = 'data_' + str(count) + '_key_1'
    #check key does not exist in dictionary
    if 'key_1' in i and key not in new_dict:
        new_dict[data[key]] = data['data_'+str(count)+'_values_0']
        count += 1
print(new_dict)
```

O/P:

```
{'1860': '20.89', '1861': '21.02', '1862': '19.93', '1863': '21.48'}
```